localFont function used from next JS fails build with error in production
Here is a function I am using to add local font in nextJS. Error in build shown in detail below.
layout.tsx
import localFont from 'next/font/local';

const content = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: './fonts/light.woff2',
      weight: '300',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: './fonts/regular.woff2',
      weight: '400',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: './fonts/bold.woff2',
      weight: '700',
      style: 'normal',
    },
  ],
  display: 'swap',
  variable: '--font-content',
  fallback: ['system-ui', 'arial'],
  adjustFontFallback: 'Times New Roman',
});

I am using following versions with docker
node - 22.2.0
nextJs - 14.2.4
yarn 4.2.2
Here is an error from build
#16 1.452   ▲ Next.js 14.2.4
#16 1.452 
#16 1.524    Creating an optimized production build ...
#16 8.896 Failed to compile.
#16 8.896 
#16 8.900 src/app/layout.tsx
#16 8.900 An error occurred in `next/font`.
#16 8.900 
#16 8.900 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ascent')
#16 8.900     at get ascent (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/font/dist/fontkit/index.js:1:797933)
#16 8.900     at getFallbackMetricsFromFontFile (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/font/dist/local/get-fallback-metrics-from-font-file.js:73:13)
#16 8.900     at nextFontLocalFontLoader (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/font/dist/local/loader.js:63:114)
#16 8.900     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
#16 8.900     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
#16 8.900     at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-font-loader/index.js:76:87
#16 8.900     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)

It's working fine when run on local machine and also build works with no error. With same versions.
In tailwind.config.js
fontFamily: {
    content: ['var(--font-content)'],
}

I tried different values for fallback & adjustFontFallback but still result is same.

In my case, I had problems with the font files. I just deleted them and downloaded them again. Maybe you should try other fonts for the test?
const notoSans = localFont({
  variable: '--font-noto-sans',
  src: [
    {
      path: './fonts/NotoSans-Light.ttf',
      weight: '300',
    },
    {
      path: './fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf',
      weight: '400',
    },
    {
      path: './fonts/NotoSans-Medium.ttf',
      weight: '500',
    },
    {
      path: './fonts/NotoSans-SemiBold.ttf',
      weight: '600',
    },
    {
      path: './fonts/NotoSans-Bold.ttf',
      weight: '700',
    },
  ],
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html
      lang='en'
      className={notoSans.className}
    >
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

Example of font layout
